# Configure Nginx to load Laravel 5.8 Site in CentOS

Tags: linux, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, centos

I have a Laravel 5.8 project locate at `/var/www/html/got/`

---

If I run `php artisan serve`, it works fine. But I'm  trying to deploy my site via nginx instead.

---

## sites-available/default

```
server {

       listen   [::]:80;
       listen   80;
       root /var/www/html/got/public;

       index index.php index.html index.htm;

       location / {
               try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;
       }

       location ~ \.php?$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
               fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
               #Prevent version info leakage
               fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
               proxy_read_timeout 300;
       }

}
```

## nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

---

I kept getting

[image]

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The nginx.conf should be something like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The files from `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory should be soft linked to the directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, never directly included.

Copy the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to reflect the domain, something like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf` and then modify the `server {}` part to reflect the following:

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name .example.com;
root "/var/www/html/got/public";
```